# recyclerview para introducir datos

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

tengo un recyclerview el cual utilizo para introducir datos a mi aplicacion. Los datos a introducir son bienes los cuales tienen un nombre y un valor. Si desde la interfaz grafica introduzco nombre y valor por orden funciona perfecto. Pero si primero introduzco los nombres y despues los valores es cuando da problemas. Hago un Log.i del Input_Array (que es en donde se almacenan los datos de entrada) y me muestra bien los valores, pero en los nombres me muestra todos con el valor del ultimo dato introducido. Es decir, si introduzco los nombres a,s,d,f y los valores 1,2,3,4 el logcat muestra: f,1  f,2  f,3  f,4.

Este es el codigo de la funcion ViewHolder, del adapter. En ella es donde se manejan los eventos onTexChange para capturar los datos de entrada, tanto el nombre como el valor de cada bien: (y este es el enlace al repositorio de github:[repo](https://github.com/palanganero/repartirHerenciaEntradaDatos))

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    EditText nombre,valor;
    Button siguiente;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nombre=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        valor= itemView.findViewById(R.id.valor);
        siguiente= itemView.findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

        nombre.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().matches(""))
                {
                    name=s.toString();
                    Bien b= new Bien();
                    b.setNombre(s.toString());
                    b.setValor(value);
                    input.set(getAdapterPosition(), b);
                }
            }
        });
        valor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().matches(""))
                {
                    value=Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                    Bien b= new Bien();
                    b.setValor(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));
                    b.setNombre(name);
                    input.set(getAdapterPosition(), b);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Tu código me parece algo enrevesado. Tienes dos fuentes de entrada y asignas eventos de escucha a ellas dos y dentro de esos eventos de escucha las escuchas a ambas. ¿Te imaginas que tuvieras 10 ó 50 fuentes de entrada y plantearas tu código del mismo modo, 50 eventos de escucha y dentro escuchando a las 50 fuentes de entrada? El principal problema aquí es un código mal organizado. Considera asignar un solo evento de escucha para todos tus elementos, determinar de algún modo qué elemento cambió y según eso asignar el dato a la instancia del elemento `Bien`.

Comment: pero tengo que añadir un `addTextChangedListener` a cada boton. ¿como puedo asignar un solo evento de escucha para todos los elementos?

Comment: El asunto fue discutido ampliamente en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5702771/5587982) en la cual hay varias respuestas muy buenas que te explican cómo hacerlo.